# Array formula is showing "#Parameter in error" error

Tags: excel, parameters, add-in

I'm working on excel with a function (from an addin) which is suppose to request a data base and  print some assets prices for different dates and different maturities. The function is used in an array formula way. The following picture gives an idea of how the data are organised :

[image]

The two first rows of the sheet were empty, I filled them with same formula as in the array without using array formula (formula cell by cell). So there seems to be a problem with the latest date only, although the data are available in the data base. When shifting the dates, the problem persists for the latest date.
I didn't have this problem a week ago (I don't usually change anything in the worksheets, except updating the dates) and I have no clue of how to address this "#Parameter in error" error.
Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Comment: This is not an Excel error code. It is a custom error message returned by the function.

Comment: The error is completely dependent on the add-in and what it expects. A quick search of the web for the function name didn't turn up results so I suspect it's an internal add-in. You'll have to contact the developer or your support folks for more help.

Answer (score 0):

So, i found a wobbly way to solve the problem. For the latest date formula, I had to change this : `=IF(WEEKDAY(DateD;2)=6;DateD-1;IF(WEEKDAY(DateD;2)=7;DateD-2;DateD))` into this : `=IF(WEEKDAY(DateD;2)=6;DateD-1;IF(WEEKDAY(DateD;2)=7;DateD-2;DateD-1+1))`. `DateD` refers to the cell in which the date is first set, using this VBA code :

```
Private Sub ButtonDateClick()
    If TextBoxDate.Value <> "" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("DateD") = Format(TextBoxDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    End If
    UserFormDate.Hide
    Application.Calculate
    MsgBox ("Date changed")
End Sub
```

I found this by pure chance. Do you guys know what difference changing `DateD` into `DateD-1+1` is actually making for the array formula?